# POSTGIS: function st_collect(geography) does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, geography-data-type

I am trying to use some Geography functions, but I am getting an error that (all) functions are not existing. I have checked other Stackexchange posts (e.g. [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/postgis-error-type-geography-does-not-exist)), but the solutions did not work for me.

Since no function is available, I assume that something is wrong with the geography tables. I am using POSTGIS 2.0.1, therefore the `geography` functions should be supported.

```
database# select postgis_full_version(); 
POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL
1.9.1, released 2012/05/15" LIBXML="2.7.3" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

I can see the geography tables in the database and the database owner also owns the geography tables.

```
 public   | geography_columns | view     | developer
 public   | geometry_columns  | view     | developer
 public   | raster_columns    | view     | developer
 public   | raster_overviews  | view     | developer
```

**What could cause the error below?**

```
function st_collect(geography) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_xMin(ST_Collect(location)) AS id, ST_xMax(ST_Colle...
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html),

> ST_Collect — Return a specified ST_Geometry value from a collection of other *geometries*.

(emphasis mine) but it seems your `location` column is of type `geography`.

Perhaps you need to convert the *geography* to a *geometry* via *casting*:

```
St_Collect (location::geometry)
```

Comment: Indeed, only a small subset of functions are implemented for geography. For all others, just cast, as suggested here.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The hint regarding geography vs. geometry reminded me that I put `geography=True` in the GeoDjango model.

Comment: If you want geography back you need to cast back.  So   ST_Collect(location::geometry)::geography