# Import SHPs and DBFs to PostgreSQL in pgAdmin 4 on a Mac

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mac, boundless-suite, shp2pgsql

I am receiving the following error when trying to import a dbf file into PostgreSQL (v 12, pgAdmin 4) using the Boundless/OpenGeo Suite for Mac `pgShapeLoader` GUI (which was recommended for Mac users in a Stack Exchange answer here, since there is no shapefile importer GUI included in the most recent Mac installation: [Shapefile loader in pgAdmin 4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217456/shapefile-loader-in-pgadmin-4)):

```
Failed SQL begins: "CREATE INDEX ON "public"."soildef" USING GIST ("geom");
COMMIT;
"
Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  column "geom" does not exist

Shapefile import failed.
```

The `pgShapeLoader` GUI worked fine for me when importing shapefiles, but it is producing the above error for the dbfs. And I know it should work because it is working for everyone using Windows for the PostGIS tutorial I'm following on Udemy (meaning, there is nothing wrong with the dbf itself).

The Windows installation of PostgreSQL/PostGIS has a shapefile loader gui `shp2pgsql-gui.exe`, but unfortunately this does not appear to be included in the Mac install. There is only a Unix executable `shp2pgsql` in the bin folder.

Are my only options for importing the dbfs to use the command line and/or to do this through QGIS, per another answer on the linked SE question/answer above? I am not finding any other solutions. Or maybe the question I should really be asking myself is simply: "How do you import a dbf into PostgreSQL on a Mac?" (Which seems a bit obvious now that I'm typing it, but I'd like to post this question anyway for anyone else who might run into this problem).

Comment: It's unclear from your question if these dBase files are just that, standalone dBase files, or whether they are associated with the shapefiles themselves. The `.dbf` data is part of the shapefile standard, so any shapefile loader should automatically include the attributes with geometry.

Comment: @Vince Ah. Didn't catch that ambiguity. They are standalone files, not part of the shapefiles.

Comment: dbf does not contain the geom? then it will need to be created - the error you see states 'geom' does not exist - look in your soildef table - you will need to create geom to create a GIST index.

Comment: @Mapperz Right, I would have thought the same, but the instructor manages to import the DBFs using the GUI without a problem. All of our inputs are the same. Only difference is he's using windows. Why wouldn't he get the same error message then?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11886/error-importing-shapefile-to-postgis-using-importer-gui

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks that link looks helpful. I tried unchecking "create spatial index..." in the import options, and then it imported successfully. So the error is obviously in trying to create the index without a geom column. I was just thrown by the instructor being able to import the .dbf data without a problem, so I assumed there was an entirely other problem at play. Maybe there is a difference between the shp2pgsql GUI he's using and the pgShapeLoader GUI I'm using. Maybe shp2pgsql just ignored the lack of a geom column and skipped creating the index, even though the option was checked off?